# python 3 форматирование текста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
print("Сумма вашего кредита {0:.2f} за  период {1:d} месяцев. Ежемесячный взнос, составит {2:.2f} "+\
      "в месяц процент банка ежемесячно составит {3:.2f} !".format(creditSum, period, result, bankProcent))
```

Выводит только последние значение адекватно, все остальные как строку. Поясните в чем ошибка?

Comment: Нужный минимальный код, на котором воспроизводится проблема. По приведенным данным - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: уберите `+\\` (чтобы объединить константы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрите на свой код:

```
print("Сумма вашего кредита {0:.2f} за период {1:d} месяцев. Ежемесячный взнос, составит {2:.2f} "+\
      "в месяц процент банка ежемесячно составит {3:.2f} !".format(creditSum, period, result, bankProcent))
```

Вы склеиваете две строки, при этом метод `format` применяется только ко второй.

Comment: Решение: `s = "...{}...{}..." + "...{}...{}..." print(s.format(...)`